# Splitting and printing comma-separated values

Tags: c, strings, csv

I stumbled upon a question on SO asking how to split a comma-separated string into individual values.

Since it's been a while since I've had any good reason to write C I'd like to ask for some feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char str[] ="coma separated,input,,,some fields,,empty";
    const char tok[] = ",";
    char * tmp = (char *)str;
    size_t count;
    for (count=0; tmp[count]; tmp[count] == tok[0] ? count++ : * tmp++) {
        //Empty loop body.
    }
    tmp = (char *)str;
    for (size_t i = 0, l = 0; i < count; i++) {
        l = strcspn (tmp, tok);
        if (l == 0) {
            printf("\"\"\n");
        } else {
            printf("\"%.*s\"\n", l, tmp);
        }
        tmp += sizeof(char) * (l + 1);
    }
    printf("\"%s\"\n", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Output as expected:

```
"coma separated"
"input"
""
""
"some fields"
""
"empty"
```

Comment: do you need to handle escaped `,` and `"` values? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `sizeof(char)` by definition is 1. `tmp += l + 1;` would be as good.
- I don't see a need to special case `l == 0`.
- You don't have to initialize `l` in a loop header: it is immediately reassigned.
- `gcc` complains about precision specifier in `printf("\"%.*s\"\n", l, tmp)` being `size_t`; unfortunately, cast is unavoidable.
- I don't see a need for 2 separate loops. A single

  ```
  char * tmp = (char *)str;
  do {
      int l = strcspn (tmp, tok);
      printf("\"%.*s\"\n", l, tmp);
      tmp += l + 1;
  } while (tmp[-1]);
  return 0;
  ```

  works equally well.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I could avoid looping twice, much appreciated.

Comment: "`tmp += l + 1`; would be as good." as `tmp` is of pointer type that would be even better. Actually if `tmp` was a pointer to `int` (and all occurrences of `char` were replaced with `int`) as the code is now it would be **incorrect**! For more info search for materials about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

As @vnp noted, the "correct" solution is much simpler.  I would make a few changes and write it as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char string[] = "comma separated,input,,,some fields,,empty";
    const char delims[] = ",";

    const char *s = string;
    do {
        size_t field_len = strcspn(s, delims);
        printf("\"%.*s\"\n", (int)field_len, s);
        s += field_len;
    } while (*s++);
}
```

Notable changes include:

- Friendlier variable names
- Don't cast away the `const`
- Ensure that `printf()` gets an `int` for the field width specifier
- Smarter loop termination test (check for the NUL terminator then increment the pointer)

### Nasty loop

Your original solution contains a loop that is particularly convoluted:

> ```
> char * tmp = (char *)str;
> size_t count;
> for (count=0; tmp[count]; tmp[count] == tok[0] ? count++ : * tmp++) {
>     //Empty loop body.
> }
> tmp = (char *)str;
> ```

As discussed previously,

- This loop, whose goal is to set `count` to the number of commas, turns out to be completely unnecessary.
- Casting away `const` is bad.

In addition,

- **The loop manipulates both `count` and `tmp`, which makes it very confusing.**  When the loop terminates, `tmp` points to `count` bytes before the end of the string.  That's just weird!

  The non-weird version would be:

  ```
  int count = 0;
  for (const char *tmp = str; *tmp; tmp++) {
      if (*tmp == tok[0]) count++;
  }
  ```

  Note the very conventional loop header: start at the beginning of `str`, walk one byte at a time until NUL is reached.  Also, `tmp` is truly temporary, and falls out of scope after the loop, so you don't have to worry about resetting it.  The loop body is straightforward as well: increment `count` for each comma.
- `* tmp++` is a superfluous pointer dereference that just adds confusion and noise.

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid having `l` as a variable name, also considering that variables shouldn't be named with just one character (excluding loop counter variables).  It can be easy for a human to mistake it as `1` (one), although the compiler understands it.

Also, there is a typo in `str[]` ("coma" should be "comma").